# Windows 10 Single Language Edition Fails Activation

Tags: windows-7, language, windows-10-upgrade, windows-activation

My question is - what version Win10 should I have downloaded to replace Win7 home premium.  I want to make another DVD to do the same on another laptop.

Computer has label.  Nirsoft Produkey found a different key.
Windows 7 has not been replaced only auto updated.
Windows 7 home, drive formatted using AOMEI (wanted clean install).
Windows 10 boot DVD made using Media Creation Tool on another computer.
Selected Windows 10 home single language user US 64bit (trying to match computer original win7 home premium)
Win 10 activation would not work with label key or produkey key.
Could it be because of language and country mix ups?
Called microsoft using the slui 4 command in Windows Run.
Auto validation did not work after putting in all the number codes.

Talked to second operator after first operator repeated my activation process and also failed.
Operator checked my label product key and it was proved to be genuine.
Operator connected to my computer via internet and said that single language version cannot be activated this way.
My Win10 was ?regraded?? and then at least 2 keys were tried and various operations using command prompt e.g. slmgr -upk, cpky, -ipk.
Eventually after about 1 hour Microsoft (well done Microsoft) were successful in activation.

Comment: You do realize you could have chosen to keep nothing, and upgraded your Windows 7 installation, from within Windows and accomplished your goal.  There was no reason to install Windows the way you did.  You installed the wrong version of Windows 10, validate Windows, even thinks its still Single Language I bet it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement of Windows 7 Home Premium is Windows 10 Home, not the single language edition. The Single Language Edition is the upgrade of Windows 8.1 Single Language, wich is only sold in emerging markets.

You can get a fresh [Windows 10 Home ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench). Select here `Windows 10`.

[image]